# Protractor locator by.repeater work with 'contains' instead of 'equals'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

In my page there is 2 ng-repeat, 'widget in widgets', 'widget in widgetsOnPage'. When I try to locate a elements by `element.all(by.repeater('widget in widgets'));` it finds elements from both of the repeats.

I try also, on the protractor example test `("\node_modules\protractor\example\example_spec.js")` to change the 'todo in todos' repeater to:

```
todoList = element.all(by.repeater('to'));
```

And the test pass.

- How can I locate the repeats that equals exactly to the string?
- That behavior is a defect on protractor or a feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`by.repeater` locator is based on `findRepeaterElement()` function. According to it's [implementation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/3d60689b423749686973227f4b26cbb494f60b66/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L176-191), it is searching for a passed in the repeater substring inside the `ng-repeat` attribute value, see this `indexOf` call inside the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < repeatElems.length; ++i) {
  if (repeatElems[i].getAttribute(attr).indexOf(repeater) != -1) {
    rows.push(repeatElems[i]);
  }
}
```

Since `widget in widgets` is a substring of `widget in widgetsOnPage`, there is a match.

---

Since the behavior is a bit surprising, I'd submit an issue to the [protractor github issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues).

Comment: I've just opened [issue #1247](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1247) check Julie / Hank answers there later on.

Comment: @elgalu thank you very much for the report, will keep track of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try for a css selector, which could include the extra text:

```
$$('[ng-repeat="widget in widgets"]');
$$('[ng-repeat="widget in widgetsOnPage"]');
```

This would restrict the output to just the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario, I would probably just make my own locator! See [protractor's documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/api.md#api-protractorby)